# Couldn't find file 'jquery' while testing rails 4 plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a rails 4 plugin with a dummy test app.

The plugin depends on nested_form which in turns depends on JQuery (but it is not defined).

My gemspec includes dependency for both runtime and development for 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'.
I ran `bundle install` and have jquery-rails used.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js` contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

I run the dummy app (`cd test/dummy; rails s`) and everything works fine, including the javascript from either nested_form or automatic detection of `data-method="delete"` on links.

When I try to run tests (from the plugin's root), I get a lot of errors each time I try to get a page:

> ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'jquery'
>    (in /..../app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
>    sprockets backtrace

If I remove the 3 js require, then everything works.

Any idea?

---

```
# Gemfile
gemspec
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'better_errors'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-nav'

# gemspec
s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 4.0'
s.add_runtime_dependency 'nested_form', '~> 0.3.2'

s.add_development_dependency 'nested_form', '~> 0.3.2'
s.add_development_dependency 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
s.add_development_dependency 'factory_girl_rails'
s.add_development_dependency 'database_cleaner'
s.add_development_dependency 'faker'
```

---

I've already tried to add `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'` in my Gemfile, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you paste the Gemfile?

Comment: Are you sure `jquery_nested_form` does not load `jquery` itself?

Comment: no, it doesn't, and the problem is the same with just jquery actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of `'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'` removed `jquery-ui`. This can be solved by using `gem "jquery-ui-rails"` for `jquery-ui` or use specific version of `gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"` as later version of gem has deleted the ui part.